# IdentityServer4 Architecture

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have integrated my asp.net core app with identityserver4 and succeeded to authenticate and authorize users, my architecture now is as follow:

I have a separate server for identityserver4 with a separate database for all user tables(asp.net core identity tables).
I have an MVC client with a separate database with table called Accounts which hold the userid from identityserver4

I need to do user management stuff I am stuck with two scenarios

1- Create, delete, update accounts from the client MVC app and create an API at the identityserver to reflect that at the table users

2- Allow the client MVC app to access the identity database with identityserver4 and directly do user management

So, what is the best architecture, one shared database for the identityserver4 and the MVC client or    or a separate database for identityserver4 and another database for the MVC client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prefer the first option. But it depends on the context and requirements. If you are creating a green-field project that might be larger after some time (which would contain more services), then I recommend you to try microservice architecture.

Microservices often scale much better than monolithic apps but the architecture and overall tech stack might be more complicated. The key point is that they are independent - so they share nothing, database not at all. It comes with other problems, for example synchronizing the databases. It is well described in the free eBook: [NET Microservices: Architecture for Containerized .NET Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/) ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/architect-microservice-container-applications/identify-microservice-domain-model-boundaries) or [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/architect-microservice-container-applications/asynchronous-message-based-communication), but you should read also other pages).

If you plan to create just small services that might be part of a non-microservice ecosystem, the 2. choice may be better.

Comment: Thank you for your replay.
I am asking about the best practice from the security point of view whatever the architecure is

Comment: I think both of the options are good enough on the security side **if they are well implemented**. It is rather architectural problem, how the services should communicate - if through database or through API. Both solutions may be implemented with security threats.